# Unable to reference another model this model belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4

The relevant bits:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to  :owner, class_name: User, foreign_key: :owner_id

  ...
  def self.lookup_and_send_emails(addresses, msg)
    addresses.each do |email|
      user = User.where(email: :email)
      if user
        invite!( user)
        SwapMailer.babysitter_request(email, msg).deliver
      else
        #send the devise/website invitation
      end
    end
  end

  def self.invite!(user)
    UsersEventInvitation.create(invite_sent_by: self.owner.id, invite_sent_to: user.id, event_id: self.id)
  end

  ...
end
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
undefined method `owner' for #<Class:0x007fa0dcd73fc8>
```

what gives here? What I'd *like* to do is assign the `current_user.id` where i'm using self.owner.id but I thought this would be a workaround since *that* wasn't working.

UPDATE:
I was calling `Event.lookup_and_send_emails(...)` from my controller. I'm now doing `@event.lookup_and_send_emails(...)`, however I *now* get `undefined method`id' for #`pointing at the the`self.owner.id`line in the`invite!` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove self from invite! And as well as lookup_and_send_emails method.  As they should instance methods. Appending self makes them class method. And when u call other method within a class method without any object it takes it as class method only.

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base ... 
 belongs_to :owner, class_name: User, foreign_key: :owner_id

 def lookup_and_send_emails(addresse s, msg) addresses.each do |email| user = User.where(email: :email) if user invite!( user)

SwapMailer.babysitter_request(email, msg).deliver else #send the devise/website invitation end end end

def invite!(user)
 UsersEventInvitation.create(invite_sent_by: self.owner.id, invite_sent_to: user.id, event_id: self.id)
end
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: @event is single object right ? Also what is the association written in user model for event ?

Comment: User has_many Events. Event is a single object: `@event = Event.new(event_params)`

Comment: actually: User 
    has_many :user_event_invitations
    has_many :events, through: :user_event_invitations

Comment: so... an Event has one owner, but many users but both are User objects. that's why the "has_many through"

Comment: Also where u doing User.where(email: email).. instead of this either use find_by_id or where with . First. As where returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `invite!` method is a class method, not an instance method.  So, it is defined on the `Class` object representing the `Event` and not any one individual event.  If you are looking to send an invite from the owner of a particular event, these need to be instance methods.  so define them with

```
def invite!(user)
```

e.g. no `self.` preceding the method definition.

Comment: Remove self from lookup_and_sendemail also.  As invite! Method is called from inside of lookup method. So it will derive instance or class method from the parent method.

Comment: ok, so I modified a bit here. I was calling `Event.lookup_and_send_emails(...)` from my controller. I'm now doing `@event.lookup_and_send_emails(...)`, however I *now* get `undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` pointing at the the `self.owner.id` line in the `invite!` method.

Comment: `User.where(email: :email)` returns a relation, a collection of users.  You probably want something like:

`User.where(email: :email).each { |user| invite!(user); SwapMailer.babysitter_request(email, msg).deliver}`